# How to flatten nested python dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to flatten the nested dictionary:

```
dict1 = {
    'Bob': {
        'shepherd': [4, 6, 3],
        'collie': [23, 3, 45],
        'poodle': [2, 0, 6],
    },
    'Sarah': {
        'shepherd': [1, 2, 3],
        'collie': [3, 31, 4],
        'poodle': [21, 5, 6],
    },
    'Ann': {
        'shepherd': [4, 6, 3],
        'collie': [23, 3, 45],
        'poodle': [2, 10, 8],
    }
}
```

I'd like to display all values in lists:
[4, 6, 3, 23, 3, 45, 2, 0, 6, 1, 2, 3,..., 2, 10, 8]

My first idea was to do in this way:

```
dict_flatted = [ i for name in names.values() for dog in dogs.values() for i in dog]
```

Though I'm getting the error. I'd be happy for tips how to handle it.

Comment: What error are you getting? You mention "the" error, but you don't actually describe it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a simple recursive function as follows.

```
def flatten(d):    
    res = []  # Result list
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key, val in d.items():
            res.extend(flatten(val))
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        res = d        
    else:
        raise TypeError("Undefined type for flatten: %s"%type(d))

    return res


dict1 = {
    'Bob': {
        'shepherd': [4, 6, 3],
        'collie': [23, 3, 45],
        'poodle': [2, 0, 6],
    },
    'Sarah': {
        'shepherd': [1, 2, 3],
        'collie': [3, 31, 4],
        'poodle': [21, 5, 6],
    },
    'Ann': {
        'shepherd': [4, 6, 3],
        'collie': [23, 3, 45],
        'poodle': [2, 10, 8],
    }
}

print( flatten(dict1) )
```

Comment: Nice!  Thanks!  I extended your code a bit to allow recursing within lists too.  Results are posted below.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use variables that don't exist.

Use this

```
dict_flatted = [ i for names in dict1.values() for dog in names.values() for i in dog]
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive function can be single line:

```
def flatten(d):
    return d if isinstance(d, list) else sum((flatten(i) for i in d.values()), [])
```

Nota: was an answer for a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51426716/3545273)

Comment: This only flattened my data only one level.

Answer (score 1):

I started with @DaewonLee's code and extended it to more data types and to recurse within lists:

```
def flatten(d):
    res = []  # type:list  # Result list
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key, val in d.items():
            res.extend(flatten(val))
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for val in d:
            res.extend(flatten(val))
    elif isinstance(d, (float, str, int)):
        res = [d]  # type: List[float] or List[str] or List[int]
    else:
        raise TypeError("Undefined type for flatten: %s" % type(d))
    return res
```

Comment: Flattened 5 levels in my data including dictionaries and lists. Thanks. Noticed that it does not preserve data structure.

Answer (score 0):

**for this specific case: (2 levels)**

1. using itertools.chain method:

   nested_dict = {1 : {'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [4,5]},
   2 : {'a' : [6],     'b' : [7,8,9]}}

   list(chain(*[v for y in nested_dict.values() for v in list(y.values())]))

   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

**using pandas:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(data=nested_dict), dtype=object)
df['chain'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(chain(*x.values.tolist())), axis=1)
```

[image]