# How to get all text inside XML tags

Tags: python, xml, parsing

[xml file snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB4xH.jpg)

From above .xml file I am extracting article-id, article-title, abstract and keywords. For normal text inside single tag getting correct results. But text with multiple tags such as:

```
 <title-group>
   <article-title>
      Acetylcholinesterase-Inhibiting Activity of Pyrrole Derivatives from a Novel Marine Gliding Bacterium,
     <italic>Rapidithrix thailandica</italic>
   </article-title>
 </title-group>
 .
 .
 same is for abstract...
```

I got output as:

```
  OrderedDict([(u'italic**', u'Rapidithrix thailandica'), ('#text', u'Acetylcholines terase-Inhibiting Activity of Pyrrole Derivatives from a Novel Marine Gliding Ba cterium,')])
```

code has considered tag  as a text and the o/p generated is also not in the sequence.

How to simply extract text from such input document as ***"Acetylcholinesterase-Inhibiting Activity of Pyrrole Derivatives from a Novel Marine Gliding Bacterium, Rapidithrix thailandica".***

I am using below python code to perform above task..

```
import xmltodict
import os
from os.path import basename
import re


with open('2630847.nxml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
    pmc_id = doc['article']['front']['article-meta']['article-id'][1]['#text']

    article_title = doc['article']['front']['article-meta']['title-group']['article-title']

    y = doc['article']['front']['article-meta']['abstract']
    y = y.items()[0]
    article_abstract = [g.encode('ascii','ignore') for g in y][1]

    z = doc['article']['front']['article-meta']['kwd-group']['kwd']
    zz = [g.encode('ascii','ignore') for g in z]
    article_keywords = ",".join(zz).replace(","," ")


    fout = open(str(pmc_id)+".txt","w")
    fout.write(str(pmc_id)+"\n"+str(article_title)+". "+str(article_abstract)+". "+str(article_keywords))
```

Can somebody please suggest corrections..

Comment: You could flatten doc...['title-group']['article-title'] (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135433/how-to-flatten-nested-python-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

xmltodict will likely be hard to use for your data. PMC journal articles are definitely *not* what the authors could have had in mind. Putting any but the most trivial XML into xmltodict is pounding a round peg into a square hole -- you might succeed, but it won't be pretty. I explain this further below under "tldr"....

Instead, I suggest you use a library whose data model fits your data better, such as xml.dom, minidom, or recent versions of BeautifulSoup. In many such libraries you just load the document with one call and then call some function like innerText() to get all the text content of it. You could even just load the document into a browser and call the Javascript innerText() function to get what you want. If the tool you choose doesn't provide innertext() already, it is:

```
def innertext(node):
    t = ""
    for curNode in node.childNodes:
        if (isinstance(curNode, Text)):
            t += curNode.nodeValue
        elif (isinstance(curNode, Element)):
            t += curNode.innerText
    return(t)
```

You could tweak that to put spaces between the text nodes, depending on your data.

Hope that helps.

==tldr==

xmltodict makes an admirable attempt at making XML "as simple as possible"; but IMHO it errs in making it *simpler* than possible.

xmltodict basically works by turning every element into a dict, with its children as the dict items, keyed by their element names. But in many cases (such as yours), XML data isn't very much like that at all. For example, an element can have many children with the same name, but a dict can't.

So xmltodict has to do something special. It turns adjacent instances of the same element type into an array (without the element type). Here's an example excerpted from https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict):

```
<and>
  <many>elements</many>
  <many>more elements</many>
</and>
```

becomes:

```
"and": {
    "many": [
        "elements", 
        "more elements"
    ]
},
```

First off, this means that xmltodict always loses the ordering information about child elements unless they are of the same type. So a section that contains a mix of paragraphs, lists, blockquotes, and so on, will either fail to load in xmltodict, or have all the scattered instances of each kind of child gathered together, completely losing their order.

The xmltodict approach also introduces frequent special-cases -- for example, you can't just get a list of all the children, or use len() to find out how many there are, etc. etc., because at every step you have to check whether you're really at a child element, or at a list of them.

Looking at xmltodict's own examples, you'll see that they mostly consist of walking down the tree by element names, but every now and then there's an integer subscript -- that's for the cases where these arrays are needed. But unless the data is unusually simple (which yours isn't), you won't know where that is. For example, if one DIV in an HTML document happens to contain only one P, the code to access the P needs one fewer subscript than with another DIV that happens to have more than one P.

It seems to me undesirable that the *number of subscripts* to get to something  depends on how many siblings it has, and their types.

Alas, the structure still isn't good enough. Since child elements may have their own child elements, just making them strings in that extra array won't be enough. Sometimes they'll have to be dicts again, with some of their items in turn perhaps being arrays, some of whose items may be dicts, and so on. Writing the correct traversal algorithm to gather up the text is significantly harder than the DOM one shown above.

To be completely fair, there *is* some XML in which the order doesn't matter logically -- for example, you could export a SQL table into an XML file, using a container element for each record with a child element for each field. The order of fields is not information, so if you load such XML into xmltodict, losing the order doesn't matter. Likewise if you serialized Python data that was *already* just a dict. But those are very specialized edge cases. xmltodict might be an excellent choice for a case like that -- but the articles you're looking at are very far from that.

Comment: I figured it out with regex techniques.. Thanks :)