# Flatten a nested dictionary representing a bill-of-material in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, tree

I have a bill of material in a nested dict that shows the components of a product.  some components themselves have sub-components.  some do not.  I am trying to transform this nested dictionary into a flat one where all components and subcomponents are under the master item, ie bring sub-components under the highest level product they ultimately build into:

nested BOM I am starting with:

[image: nested dict]

The 'flat' dictionary result I want (notice everything is under a product (P):

[image]

This is what I tried so far with little success.  Maybe my code needs to be recursive to take into account the unknown depth?  Any tips HUGELY appreciated.

```
thicc_bom={
'P1': {'C1': 6, 'C2': 6, 'C3': 1},
'P2': {'C2': 6, 'C3': 1},
'P3': {'C4': 1},
'C1': {'SC1': 1, 'SC2': 1},
'C4': {'SC3': 1, 'SC4': 1},
'SC4': {'SSC1': 1},}

flat_bom=defaultdict(dict)
for p in thicc_bom:
    for c in thicc_bom[p]:
        if list(c)[0] in list(thicc_bom):
            for d in thicc_bom[c]:
                flat_bom[c][d]=thicc_bom[c][d]
        else:
            flat_bom[p][c]=thicc_bom[p][c]
```

Comment: Duplicate, answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135433/how-to-flatten-nested-python-dictionaries

Comment: I disagree with the dupe. The proposed duplicate isn't a recursively defined tree structure as this is. Can OP post the expected output, please? If `flat_bom` is indeed to be a dict, keys must be unique, so I'd anticipate something like a list of associated components for each part number.

Comment: In fact, the input dict also has dupes, so it's not the dict you think it is. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my errors.  I made these corrections to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @TastySlowCooker for pointing out the correct `thicc_bom`. This will get you the result:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

thicc_bom={
    'P1': {'C1': 6, 'C2': 6, 'C3': 1},
    'P2': {'C2': 6, 'C3': 1},
    'P3': {'C4': 1},
    'C1': {'SC1': 1, 'SC2': 1},
    'C4': {'SC3': 1, 'SC4': 1},
    'SC4': {'SSC1': 1},
}

# recursive method
def descend(key, bom):
    if key in bom:
        # for-loop is doubled so preferred order is realized (BFS vs. DFS)
        for sub_key, sub_val in bom[key].items():
            yield sub_key, sub_val
        for sub_key, sub_val in bom[key].items():
            for result in descend(sub_key, bom):
                yield result

# main 
results = {}
for product in filter(lambda p: p.startswith('P'), thicc_bom):
    results[product] = {}
    for component, qty in descend(product, thicc_bom):
        results[product][component] = qty
print(results)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [
        [product, component, qty]
        for product, sub_results in results.items()
        for component, qty in sub_results.items()],
    columns = ['Part Number', 'Component', 'Quantity']
)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
{'P1': {'C1': 6, 'C2': 6, 'C3': 1, 'SC1': 1, 'SC2': 1}, 'P2': {'C2': 6, 'C3': 1}, 'P3': {'C4': 1, 'SC3': 1, 'SC4': 1, 'SSC1': 1}}
   Part Number Component  Quantity
0           P1        C1         6
1           P1        C2         6
2           P1        C3         1
3           P1       SC1         1
4           P1       SC2         1
5           P2        C2         6
6           P2        C3         1
7           P3        C4         1
8           P3       SC3         1
9           P3       SC4         1
10          P3      SSC1         1
```