# Check for existence of False as value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there an easy way to find occurrence of *False* as value, anywhere in Python nested dictionary. I can of course loop through the keys and values but, maybe there is a better way, especially when we do not know the depth of nested dictionary.

Example below dictionary should return False, as there is one occurrence of False

```
{'metric1': {'details': {'baseline': {'actual': 1,
                                      'lower_bound': 1,
                                      'result': True,
                                      'upper_bound': 2}},
             'result': True},
 'metric2': {'details': {'baseline': {'actual': 0,
                                      'lower_bound': 1,
                                      'result': False,
                                      'upper_bound': 2}},
             'result': None},
 'metricbool': {'details': None, 'result': True}}
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have a reverse lookup, so looping through the contents is the only option.

Comment: One way to do it would be [flattening the dict recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39135486/2550406) and then looping over the values in the list. But in the end, this is also just looping. It just makes it easy to deal with unknown structure of nesting.

Comment: Is the False always going to be in a `'result'` entry? And can there ever be any other nested dictionaries other than the given examples? With that kind of information you can code the most efficient search pattern, but there's no generalised way to search arbitrarily nested dictionaries without loops or comprehensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `all` with recursion:

```
def has_true(d):
   return all(has_true(i) and ('result' not in i or i['result']) if isinstance(i, dict) else True for i in d.values())

data = {'metric1': {'details': {'baseline': {'actual': 1, 'lower_bound': 1, 'result': True, 'upper_bound': 2}}, 'result': True}, 'metric2': {'details': {'baseline': {'actual': 0, 'lower_bound': 1, 'result': False, 'upper_bound': 2}}, 'result': True}, 'metricbool': {'details': None, 'result': True}} 
print(has_true(data))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Comment: Which is just looping... It's a good way to do it, I'd copy and paste this answer, but the OP does specify without looping through the keys and values.

Comment: @MatBailie I think one can assume that the user is referring to "looping" in the context of more shallow input dictionaries. Nested structures cannot easily be traversed by looping alone. Of course, `map` can used as well, see my edit.

Comment: I am fine with this approach @Alax1234. Your solution always returns False on my dataset (even if value of 'result' is True in all occurrences). If you can fix it in your answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: @GauravPathak I updated the solution so that it only checks values with a key of `"result"`

Comment: Why does `has_true(data)` return `False` even though `data` has plenty of `True`? And the question is about looking for `False`, isn't it?

Comment: @superbrain the goal is to look for *any* instance of `False` in the structure. Thus, `has_true` should return `False` if the value for any `result` key is `False` (including truthy false). If the expected result was `True` if any instance of `False` existed in the structure, then I think `has_false` would be more appropriate

Comment: @Ajax1234, can you check the solution against - data = {'metric1': {'details': {'baseline': {'actual': 1, 'lower_bound': 1, 'result': True, 'upper_bound': 2}}, 'result': True}, 'metric2': {'details': {'baseline': {'actual': 0, 'lower_bound': 1, 'result': False, 'upper_bound': 2}}, 'result': True}, 'metricbool': {'details': None, 'result': True}}

Comment: `all_true` might be a more appropriate name then.

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps amusing hack:

```
import sys, copy

def contains_False(obj):
    r0 = sys.getrefcount(False)
    _ = copy.deepcopy(obj)
    r1 = sys.getrefcount(False)
    return r1 > r0
```